Why don't X-ray machines at airports cause single event effect damage in electronics?
I have a few questions related to the topic.  I am confused about a few aspects after reading up about these effects and photoelectricity.

The title basically.
From the photoelectric effect, I would expect the metals, sensors in circuits, etc. to emit a current due to high frequency radiation. Let us consider a photodiode. I understand that the amount of current produced is dependent on the intensity and energy of emitted electron is dependent on frequency. How does this increased energy translate to an electric response? Will my ammeter show any change with frequency?
Will this high energy electron cause damage to the electronic circuit? If no, why? If yes, why don't we see this happen with X-ray machines?
For electronics like photodiodes and light sensors, should they be damaged if exposed to high frequency light (intensity is same) outside of the expected range basically? If yes, again it comes back to the original question: Why doesn't it happen in X-rays?


Have you tried to calculate the photo-current based on surface area and average X-ray machine incident power on that surface area? Have you then factored in that conductors are not PN junctions hence there is no real dc effect.

And added to the other comment: all the devices are powered off...

Single event effects (like single event upsets, single event latchups, etc) are usually caused by high energy particles that deposit energy into the substrate or a junction, or the capacitor in a DRAM, when they hit, which causes the effect.

@SolarMike that is usually not the case, right? Nobody turns off their watches, if I had to guess, most don't turn off their cell phones (and cell phones typically these days do check their light sensor regularly; some phones will also accidentally have their cameras on, especially because they're locked when put into the bin, but might have gotten activated by accident and now are looking for a face to face-unlock), literally nobody can turn off the RTC and thus necessary power circuit in laptops and phones…

@SolarMike LOL. Some 20 years ago, somewhere in Northern Canada, we were in a rush, so in went an open running laptop, connected to a cellphone, happily uploading files or mail as it went through the machine (IIRC the personnel were rather amused by it as well).

Send your phone through with the camera running in video mode next time, you'll definitely see some hot pixels, especially if the airport is using a CT scanner.
Luckily, those are just temporary.

I did have few USB flash devices develop unreadable sectors when subjected to sequental security x-ray imaging. They were otherwise OK both before and after that. Internal SSDs did not suffer from the same exposition.

@fraxinus Or did they  (and were just good at covering it up)???

@Michael probably both. Flash memory always uses deep ECC and in some cases can tolerate as much as 5% flipped bits. And, in some cases it has to - not because of radiation, but because of the low quality.

Short answer: The X-ray photons are not strong enough to cause single event upsets, but the margin is small. PCB and chip structure provide partial shielding, and single bit-flips are unlikely to cause noticeable effects.
Affected components
This question is very broad, as there are many electrical components that are affected by radiation in different ways. Most common of them:

Flash memory: radiation can change stored information by affecting the charge in the isolated gate electrode. Radiation can also degrate the insulation, resulting in long-term damage.
Dynamic RAM: radiation can change stored charge in gate capacitor, which would change stored information. The periodic refreshing reduces the probability.
Static RAM and other logic: These do not have floating charge storage, so any disturbing radiation has to do so in a single event upset. The single photon needs to have high enough energy to change the state of a transistor before the voltage has time to equalize through circuit wires. With even higher energy, permanent damage to insulation layers could occur.

X-ray photon energies used in scanners are in range of about 20 keV to 50 keV. For Intel 10 nm chip technology node the effective transistor gate capacitance starts at 100 aF and increases with transistor size. From capacitor energy equation we can calculate that with 50 keV and 100 aF, a single photon could cause voltage change of up to 400 mV. With the CPU core voltages of around 1.2 V, this gets close to the levels where bit flips could occur anywhere in the logic. In practice wiring capacitance and the imperfect charge transfer from X-ray photon to the transistor reduce the probability significantly.
For flash and DRAM memory there is a further concern, as the energy does not have to come from a single photon. Instead the charge can build up from multiple impacts.
This research paper gives a capacitance of 90 aF for 110 nm flash cells. That is a bit dated, but on the other hand smaller technology nodes do not reduce capacitances that fast as both dielectric distance and area are reduced. A couple of x-ray photons hitting the same cell could easily change its bit value.
DRAM memory cells have capacitance of about 6 fF (= 6000 aF). This is high enough that hundreds of photons would be required. Because DRAM is periodically refreshed, the hundred photons would have to hit a single cell within a 50 millisecond period.
Permanent degradation could occur if the radiation was strong enough to displace atoms in the chip structure. However all research I can find on permanent IC damage caused by radiation begins at 5 MeV photon energies and goes to 100 MeV or more. So it seems reasonable to expect that less than 50 keV x-rays do not have this effect.
Photon flux
Airport scanning gives a dose of around 0.2 mSv per a pass through the scanner. Calculating based on 50 keV photon energy this is equivalent to about 25e9 photons absorbed per kilogram of tissue. Absorption of silicon compared to water is about 10x higher. Taking into account the density, this gives about 6e14 photons per cubic meter.
For a 10x10x50 nm transistor gate on a chip, we get average of one photon per 3 billion transistors. Hits on metallic wiring have a reduced effect due to wiring capacitance and inductance. If we calculate over the whole chip area, we get about 100 000 photons absorbed in chip active layers per scan.
A typical chip has a couple of billion transistors, so there is a good chance that at least one of them gets hit directly. Many thousands get indirect hits through wiring. However, it is extremely unlikely that a single transistor would get hit multiple times during a single scan. If we leave a flash memory in the x-ray scanner, we could start to expect bit errors after a few years.
Shielding
The above discussion has assumed that the radiation gets to the components with no attenuation. This is not usually the case.
On component level, advanced chips usually use flip chip construction. Here the active parts of the chip are placed towards the PCB surface. From bottom side this is shielded by the PCB material and any copper ground layers, and from the top side by the passive silicon. Any photons that get absorbed in these have no effect on the chip functionality.
Furthermore, EMC concerns often requires metallic shields on the PCBs or in the enclosures. These further shield the components.
For reference, here are the attenuation lengths of x-rays for relevant materials. Attenuation length is the distance after which 1/e = 36 % of energy remains.

Copper: 50 µm
FR4 (glass + epoxy): 5 mm
Silicon: 1 mm
Iron: 100 µm

The absorption is not huge, but counting all parts of a typical mobile phone, we get at least 2 absorption lengths worth of material in the way.
This is confirmed by looking at x-ray images of electronics, where they appear mostly but not completely opaque.
This further reduces the probability of photon hits calculated above.
Effects of errors
High-density flash chips use error correction coding to correct random data errors. These typically occur due to electrical noise and manufacturing defects, but the same mechanism will correct single bit errors caused by radiation.
Consumer-grade logic circuits do not contain any correction circuitry, so a bit flip will directly affect the result. The effect of the bit flip will depend on what the chip is doing. In typical usage, CPU cores are idle most of the time and a bit flip has no effect at all. If the CPU is processing video or photo content, a single pixel of wrong color is rarely even noticed. But if the bit flip affects a memory address, that could crash a single application or the whole operating system.
Sometimes a photon hit could cause a latch-up condition, where excessive current will flow and can burn a transistor. Modern chips are designed for some tolerance and resistance against latch-ups as they can be caused by electrostatic discharges and other voltage spikes. In any case, a latch-up requires significantly higher photon energy to occur than a bit flip.
Comparison to other radiation sources
Cosmic rays have much higher per-photon energy (100 kEv and higher) but lower flux (about 1 hit per chip per hour). The risk of a cosmic ray hitting your chip is lower per second, but they are exposed all the time. And because of the high energy, cosmic rays are much more likely to produce bit flips or other effects when they hit a transistor.
Earth's atmosphere blocks a large part of cosmic radiation. How much gets through depends on altitude. The increase of radiation during a flight in an airplane is partially offset by the metal structure providing some shielding, and in any case you spend more time on the ground rather than in an airplane.
Conclusion
The safety margin is small, but currently single event upsets are unlikely with the current chip technology and the X-ray photon energy levels.
Future development of chip technology may reduce the internal capacitances to a level where the risk becomes practically significant. This could be offset by adding more shielding layers.

Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I truly appreciate your effort in summarizing the effects for different types of components. Can you also help me understand the fundamental question I had regarding photoelectricity? How does change in energy of photon translate to an electric response?

@needbrainscratched That might be a better fit for physics SE. The short explanation is that the photon energy dislocates electrons. I must admit that the answer here is a bit of a simplification, as not only does the energy of the photons matter but also the energy levels available for electrons inside the chip.

@needbrainscratched Here are a few resources that could help you: A, B. Of these, A is high level and B gets very technical. In particular, check diagram on page 11 of A, it shows how a high energy particle leaves an ionization track until its energy is depleted.

A lovely answer. I tried to work out who had posted that before I got to the end and failed.

The total radiation dose your computer receives (suppose it's in sleep mode) in a baggage X-ray machine is of the order of 1mrad. That's about as much as it gets in a day anyway from background radiation. So if you're not seeing bits flipping all the time just sitting there for a couple days..
The energy is also relatively low- of the order of 20keV- 'soft' X-rays. According to the below paper, with an anode voltage of 55kV the peak emission is in the range 15-25keV.
By contrast, for some applications we test using particles hundreds of times more energetic. At that energy level parameter shifts, upsets and cumulative device damage is observed, not surprisingly.
Research of X-ray induced single event soft errors in 45 nm SRAM by Yang Zhang et. al. DOI 10.7567/1347-4065/aae9f6 has some information that indicates it takes many krad for significant errors in a 2M x 16bit SRAM using a Philips X-ray machine with 55kV anode voltage.
I put my computer (in sleep mode) through 5 different X-ray machines in the last day or two and did not notice any issues- of course if a bit or two was flipped in 32G I might not notice.

I'll add a personal experience, prior to changes/improvements that followed 9/11 in the US. I brought along my NaI scintillation unit. I took some readings before take-off, at home, and then again when at about 35,000' altitude on the way to Burbank. I was completely surprised by the results. In terms of soft tissue damage, that 2 hour flight (it's a little shorter but not much so, from Portland to Burbank) yielded about a year's at-home dose. An aluminum tube at altitude produces a cosmic ray shower inside the cabin. Given that, I'm not at all worried about the security systems in use.

@periblepsis Nice. I imagine the aluminum becomes somewhat radioactive too- in a particle accelerator beam it apparently produces $^{24}$Na with a half-life of 15 hours. So even the cabin cleaners get some exposure.

I did have a chance, separate flight (I was traveling back and forth every week for a year and a half at the time, working at Lockheed), to sit next to an active commercial airline pilot from United. I mentioned these results to him and asked if his employers discussed things like this with him. He said that they had been asked to "wear a badge" for a while, but that they (his employer) had refused to tell him their results. He had wondered about why, but hadn't given it a lot of thought -- until I brought up my question, anyway.

My personal frequent flying in the past lead to the damage of RFID card (like of Mifare standard or similar) issued for public transportation in my city. It started being reported as invalid by scanners and needed replacement. When I asked at card-issuing counter how frequently this happens with their city cards, they said I am the only one. (It is good to realize that in not-so-dense cities like mine, frequent flying travelers do not use public transport (so that more testing cases would appear) because they have social and other prejudices against it, preferring only taxis and private cars.)

@periblepsis that suggest you got quite a substantial dose of radiation over that period. Do you consider that significance. I've done quite a lot of international traveling such a lot of international travel but not anywhere near that total duration

@RussellMcMahon Part of the flight is in rising and falling in altitude. I extrapolated the total on the assumption that the total flight was at peak elevation. It wasn't. And that was only a single measurement. (The stewardess ordered me to shut it off, as disturbing their other passengers.) I think I received less than 50 years of background in that year and a half. But medical scans add up for lots of folks, doubling the background figure. Astronauts experience much worse. And airline pilots, too. Besides, I've ceased all air travel except as a private pilot. I don't sweat it. Paid good!

I'll just add a couple things based off my experience working in the space industry. We typically divide radiation effects on semiconductor devices into two categories: total ionizing dose (TID) and single-event effects (SEE).
When a semiconductor is hit with ionizing photons (the main source of TID), it has to get hit "the right way" to have an effect. For digital circuit transistors, the main susceptible component is the gate insulator, which is typically silicon dioxide. Ionizing radiation will charge this gate insulator over time. This increases leakage currents and changes the Vgson of the device. If the TID is high enough, the transistor could be permanently turned on regardless of the gate voltage. However this takes much more exposure than the X-Ray scanner provides. Just flying on the plane probably exposes the electronics to more radiation than the scanner. Semiconductors affected by TID will anneal after exposure and much of the charge built up in the insulator will eventually dissipate.
On the other hand, if the x-ray hits the gate electrode of the transistor, it can absolutely generate current, but its energy is not high enough to charge the gate and turn it on unless multiple x-rays hit the gate before it is driven by the circuit again (which is unlikely).
For analog devices, X-Rays can affect the signal. Although the energy isn't high enough to cause a digital bit flip, it is high enough to create errors in an analog signal. This is obvious when we do radiation testing on image sensors. During the test, the sensors get bombarded with gamma-rays, and the output images look like gray static from an old television that lost its signal. When we turn off the radiation, some of the static remains due to the charge in the gate insulators, however most of this disappears after a couple days due to the sensor annealing. Once again, the energy is not high enough to damage the image sensors. For photodiodes specifically, the quantum efficiency at those wavelengths is very small. Most of the x-rays or gamma rays either get reflected or just pass right through without interacting with the diode at all.
In both the digital and analog cases, x-ray and gamma ray photons usually don't have enough energy to cause a single-event effect. They can in some cases if the conditions are right, but not usually. Single-event effects are usually caused by higher-energy particles (typically cosmic rays or heavier high-energetic particles like protons or neutrons). These events can cause a bit-flip, latch-up, gate rupture, or a host of other problems.

I wonder if you could reproduce the "static" effect by putting your phone on video record when you send it thru the x-ray :)

@ThreePhaseEel I wonder if it would show anything. We exposed a device that used image sensors to a 100MeV proton beam (and it acted up) for space testing, but that's a far cry from a baggage X-ray. If I remember I'll try it next week, lol.
